# Impossible to deploy app in heroku - it searches ruby 2.0.0p195

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've deploying our app with rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.0.0p0 without problems in heroku. However, today suddenly I couldn't deploy it. This is the log, it seems the only difference in our project is the version of ruby 2.0.0, which is trying to be installed:

```
Counting objects: 42, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 3.17 KiB, done.
Total 25 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find money-rails-0.8.0 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

It seems that it cannot find the money-rails gem (version 0.8.0), but in localhost is working perfectly, and also until yesterday in heroku. I think it's has to be with the new ruby version as it's the only visible change regarding the gems...

Anyone with the same problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not have changed anything but it appears the author of money-rails has yanked 0.8.0 and replaced it with 0.8.1. See http://rubygems.org/gems/money-rails for details.

You would have to do a `bundle update` and commit Gemfile.lock and redeploy and all should be good.

Comment: Exactly, this is the problem. Thanks!! I just realized now, I was coming back to SO in order to answer my own question anyway. Thanks again!!